# What LLM have large output token limit?

Tags: token, large-language-model

We understand that OpenAI models are limited in their token output capacity. For instance, with latest gpt-4-turbo, if we input a query of about 10,000 tokens, the output generated cannot exceed 4,095 tokens. On the other hand, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k, which is now considered a part of legacy, has a combined limit for input and output of 16,000 tokens. This means one could input 6,000 tokens and expect an output of up to 10,000 tokens.

In my situation, I need to input roughly 15,000 tokens and expect an output of nearly the same amount. Which LLM have a large output tokens limit?

[I have tried a gpt4-preview-0125 on playground and it doesn't allow more than 4095 tokens in output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1KRc.png)

[Whereas, gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613 allows us to allocate the 16,000 token limit between input and output according to our preferences.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmeB.png)